# Is overloaded virtual behavior well defined?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have code similar to the below example in a code base I work on regularly. It causes "overloaded virtual" warnings. I'm not certain what the author intended and I'm not certain the implementation is correct, or perhaps it's correct by accident? Either way, I want to change it to more explicitly do the right thing. Given the following example below, what do you expect to be printed, 11 or 12? Is the behavior governed by the standard and where can I read more about it?

```
class ABC {
public:
    virtual int test(double i) = 0;
    virtual int test(long i) = 0;
};

class BaseImpl : public ABC {
public:
    virtual int test(double i) {return static_cast<int>(i + 1);}
    virtual int test(long i) {return static_cast<int>(i + 1);}
};

class Derived : public BaseImpl {
public:
    int test(double i) {return static_cast<int>(i + 2);}
};


int main()
{
    auto* d = new Derived();
    ABC* b = dynamic_cast<ABC*>(d);
    long arg = 10;
    std::cout << d->test(arg) << "\n";
    std::cout << b->test(arg) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What happens to the warnings if you add `virtual ~ABC() = default;` to the `ABC` class? Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/Vsco3Q

Comment: No warning(s) live: https://godbolt.org/z/C7tikl (SO paranoid settings, clang, g++, MSVC) - please quote the exact warning, compilation flags and the compiler used.

Comment: The shown code is well-formed.

Comment: The behavior has to do with function overloading, try adding `using BaseImpl::test` to Derived

Comment: Suggestion. Add the `override` specifier to the functions in `BaseImpl` and `Derived`. If you make a mistake, thinking that you've overridden a function and you mark it with `override`, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: @JVApen You mean "has to do with name lookup".

Comment: My bad, you are right

Comment: You must add `-Woverloaded-virtual` to get the warning because it's not included in `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

Comment: Note that `dynamic_cast` is not needed for casting from a derived pointer to a base pointer. You can simply write `ABC* b = d;`

Comment: An almost identical situation is explained nicely on isocpp: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#hiding-rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is overloaded virtual behavior well defined?

Yes, the behaviour of the example is well defined.

> Given the following example below, what do you expect to be printed, 11 or 12?

The correct output to expect is 12 first, then 11. The overload declared in `Derived` hides all overloads from the base scopes.

This may not be obvious though, and someone might expect the `long` overload to be selected from the base class such that the output would be 11 and 11. If that is the intended behaviour, then you need to re-declare the other overloads in the derived class. Líke this:

```
class Derived : public BaseImpl {
public:
    using BaseImpl::test;
    int test(double i) {return static_cast<int>(i + 2);}
```

> Is the behavior governed by the standard

Yes.

> and where can I read more about it?

The official source would be the standard.

Comment: To summarize, *all* overloads in the more base class are hidden, so in this case it would implicitly covert the `10L` argument to a double because that is the only definition is sees?

Comment: @ktb the overridden double overload would be the only visible declaration, yes.